# Show/Hide Divs using jQuery and ACF

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a dropdown list with a default and additional 3 options. I want to hide and show the divs based on the selection.
If the selection is default all the divs should be visible. Otherwise based on the selection, the divs should show or hide. 
However my jQuery code doesn't seem to work. I have no clue why. Here is the code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">. </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
            if ( this.value == '1')
            {
                $(".partition").show();
            }
            else
            {
                $(".partition").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the html code is

```
<select id="purpose" style="width:33%;height:50px;border:0px;background: #dadada; font-size:x-large;">
    <option selected><b>Type de matériel</b></option>
    <option value="1">Poster</option>
    <option value="2">Books</option>
    <option value="3">Audio</option>
</select>
<div class="partition">
    <?php the_field('poster_heading_1'); ?>
    <?php 
        $image = get_sub_field('partition_image');
        if( !empty($image) ):
            ?>
                <a href="<?php the_sub_field('partition_pdf'); ?>" target="_blank"> 
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                </a>
            <?php  the_sub_field('partition_text'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: this.value should be $(this).val()

Comment: Let me understand.. You should to have 3 partition div, right?

Comment: No the other two divs are partition-1 and partition-2
The issue is resolved using $(this).val() but the default selected option is hiding the divs as well. I want the default option to show all the divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you should have 3 partition div to work like you said, each div should have the id number equals select option value that you want to show. Check this code and let me say if this is what you need.

jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">. </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#purpose').on('change', function() { 
            var val = $(this).val();
            console.log(val);
            if ( val == '0' ) { 
                $(".partition").show(); 
            } else { 
                $(".partition").hide(); 
                $("#partition-" + val).show(); 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select id="purpose" style="width:33%;height:50px;border:0px;background: #dadada; font-size:x-large;">
    <option selected value="0"><b>Type de matériel</b></option>
    <option value="1">Poster</option>
    <option value="2">Books</option>
    <option value="3">Audio</option>

</select>


<div class="partition" id="partition-1">
    <?php the_field('poster_heading_1'); ?>
    <?php 
    $image = get_sub_field('partition_image');
    if( !empty($image) ):
        ?>
    <a href="<?php the_sub_field('partition_pdf'); ?>" target="_blank"> <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"> </a>
    <?php  the_sub_field('partition_text'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Now it is only showing when the default option is selected. It ain't working for the selected option. 
Why did you change the id to partition-1 when we are using the div class in the jQuery ".partition"

Comment: To show one and hide others you need to separate divs by different values. Your divs should have an identifier that corresponds with select values. My code is only an example. You should have 3 partitions div. partition-1 to show Poster, partition-2 to show Books and partition-3 to show Audio. This way you can control what to show and what to hide

Comment: Did the trick. Had to change the <div class="partition" id="partition-1"> to <div class="partition-1">

Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, just corrected a bit of the jquery

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#purpose').change(function() {
if ( $(this).val() == '1')
{
$(".partition").show();
}
else
{
$(".partition").hide();
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: It worked. But it is hiding it for the default value as well. How can I keep it for both default and selected option ?